# efficiently test if QSet contains element and insert if it is not there

Tags: c++, qt

I need to check if a `QSet` contains a certain value and if it is not there, I want to  insert it and return a boolean value indicating whether the value was inserted (`true`) or whether it had already been there (`false`). My question is how to do this efficiently. The following code actually calculates the hash and searches the set two times. This is very inefficient.

```
QSet<QString> names;
bool inserted = false;
QString name = "Dave";
if (!names.contains(name))
{
  inserted = true;
  names.insert(name);
}
```

Comment: probably not what you are looking for, but `std::set::insert` does exactly what you want

Comment: I need `QSet` for a reason. I would be OK with `std::unordered_set` but then I would need to bother with custom hash function of `QString`.

Comment: yeah I already assumed you use it for a reason, I am just surprised why `QSet::insert` does work similar

Comment: `QSet::insert` documentation is a bit insufficient. It says it returns an iterator to the inserted value. But is not clear if it returns the iterator also when the value is already there. My testing revealed it does. Nevermind, fortunately I quickly found the correct answer to my question myself. I promise, I will ask more difficult questions next time. :)

Comment: no problem for me. Assuming it isnt a duplicate imho its a good question

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, immediately after I posted the question I realized this is very easy. Anyway, I think I will keep the question for others.

```
int size = names.count();
names.insert(name);
bool inserted = names.count() > size;
```